# find top k records in python spark structured streaming

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I want to calculate top k records in PySpark structured streaming, I can sort the data by word frequency now, but after I tried a lot ways neither could it output top k record, are there some elegant way to do that?

Gere is my code:

```py
## split the tweet into words, retaining timestamps
## split() splits each line into an array, and explode() turns the array into multiple rows
words = jsonoutput.select(
    explode(split(jsonoutput.tweet, ' ')).alias('word'),
    jsonoutput.state,
    jsonoutput.time_create
)

## launching query (query_json) that contains the parsed JSON records
windowedCounts = words.groupBy(
    window(words.time_create, "1 minutes", "1 minutes"),
    words.state,
    words.word
).count().orderBy('window','state','count')

query_json = windowedCounts.writeStream \
                       .outputMode("complete") \
                       .format("memory") \
                       .queryName("wc_test") \
                       .start()
```

And when I run spark sql:

```
spark.sql("select * from wc_test limit 15").show(15,False)
```

The output is :

```
+---------------------------------------------+-----+---------+-----+
|window                                       |state|word     |count|
+---------------------------------------------+-----+---------+-----+
|[2017-11-17 16:51:00.0,2017-11-17 16:52:00.0]|AL   |broke    |1    |
|[2017-11-17 16:51:00.0,2017-11-17 16:52:00.0]|AL   |up       |1    |
|[2017-11-17 16:51:00.0,2017-11-17 16:52:00.0]|AL   |they     |1    |
|[2017-11-17 16:51:00.0,2017-11-17 16:52:00.0]|AL   |Guess    |1    |
|[2017-11-17 16:51:00.0,2017-11-17 16:52:00.0]|AL   |lol      |1    |
|[2017-11-17 16:51:00.0,2017-11-17 16:52:00.0]|CA   |wrestling|1    |
|[2017-11-17 16:51:00.0,2017-11-17 16:52:00.0]|CA   |to       |1    |
|[2017-11-17 16:51:00.0,2017-11-17 16:52:00.0]|CA   |save     |1    |
|[2017-11-17 16:51:00.0,2017-11-17 16:52:00.0]|CA   |money    |1    |
|[2017-11-17 16:51:00.0,2017-11-17 16:52:00.0]|CA   |Time     |1    |
|[2017-11-17 16:51:00.0,2017-11-17 16:52:00.0]|CA   |for      |1    |
|[2017-11-17 16:51:00.0,2017-11-17 16:52:00.0]|CA   |some     |1    |
|[2017-11-17 16:51:00.0,2017-11-17 16:52:00.0]|CA   |fresh    |1    |
|[2017-11-17 16:51:00.0,2017-11-17 16:52:00.0]|CA   |shoes    |1    |
|[2017-11-17 16:51:00.0,2017-11-17 16:52:00.0]|FL   |skype    |1    |
+---------------------------------------------+-----+---------+-----+
```

The `jsonoutput` is created from `spark.readStream`, and the class is `DataFrame[value: string, parsed_field: struct<lat:float,lon:float,tweet:string,time_create:string>, lat: float, lon: float, tweet: string, time_create: string, state: string]`

Comment: Sorry, I am bit confused.. what are you trying to achieve?Do you need top K records over the window of 1 minute?

Comment: @AkhilanandBenkalVenkanna, yes, I want to find top k records in each state over the window of 1 minute, now I get all records for each state, but I just want to fetch top k records from that.